# How to stop a row from show on Null count in query Access 2010

Tags: count, null, ms-access-2010

Here is the problem. I have a table and the table is 100% completed. There are no null values in the table. The table is broken down to:
 Division > Region > RAPM > Status > Disposition

I want to count how many times "Training" is in [Disposition] for a [Region] using a query.

The error I get is when a [Region] has 0 "Training" in [Disposition] the count is a coming back as Null so the entire row is not shown.

How do i get the count to come back as "0" so I can keep the [Division], [Region], & [RAPM] in the results for reporting even if there is 0 count for training.

I have tried NZ() but this will not work because there is technically no Null cell to be converted.

Here is the statement:

```
SELECT tblAlignment.Division, tblAlignment.Region,tblAlignment.RAPM, Count(tblCase.Dispostion) AS CountofTraining
FROM tblCase INNER JOIN tblAlignment ON (tblCase.Region = tblAlignment.Region) AND (tblCase.Store = tblAlignment.[Store Number])
Where (((tblCase.Status)="Closed") AND ((tblCase.Disposition)="Training")
Group BY tblAlignment.Division, tblAlignment.Region, tblAlignment.RAPM
HAVING (((tblAlignment.Division)=[Forms]![frmDashboardNative]![NavigationSubform].[Form]![NavigationSubform].[Form]![Combo16]))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the complete answer, but my reputation is not high enough to comment so this is the only way I can respond. To get a fuller answer you would need to provide more detailed table structure including primary keys and relationships between the tables. Making guesses from what you have provided I can make a couple of suggestions, but your post raises a few questions:

1. You say you want to count related entries based on same Region, but your join links on Region **and** Site. Is there a relationship between Site and Region? Can a single site only ever appear in one Region? If so then I think this information should possibly be in a separate table.
2. I think the `HAVING` condition should actually be in the `WHERE` clause.
3. I think you may have duplicated the `![NavigationSubform].[Form]`

Anyway, a slightly more generic example of one way of achieving what you're after would be:

```
SELECT a.Region, Nz(b.RecordCount, 0) AS FinalCount
FROM TableA a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Region, Count(*) AS RecordCount
           FROM TableB
           WHERE Status = "Closed" AND Disposition = "Training"
           GROUP BY Region) AS b ON a.Region = b.Region
WHERE a.Division = [Combo16]
```

Hope this is of some help.